# Compare and return HashMap for given value

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have a hashmap which is like the below :

```
someMap= new HashMap<Integer, String>();
someMap.put(1, "variable1");
someMap.put(2, "variable2");
someMap.put(3, "variable3");
someMap.put(4, "variable4");
someMap.put(5, "variable5");
```

and i have a java class like the below :

```
public class SomeVO {

      Long someNumber;
      String  shortDesc;

    public Long getSomeNumber() {
        return someNumber;
    }
    public void setSomeNumber(Long someNumber) {
        this.someNumber = someNumber;
    }

    public String getShortDesc() {
        return shortDesc;
    }
    public void setShortDesc(String shortDesc) {
        this.shortDesc = shortDesc;
    }

}
```

in database i have values like

```
someNumber and short-description
```

when i query database i return a list which will have the above information :

```
List<SomeVO > existingSomeNumberAndShortDescriptionList
```

now i have to compare this `List` withe `someMap` and return two maps which will have variable as key and short Description for that variable.

like i have to compare from the `existingSomeNumberAndShortDescriptionList` and i need to have final results like

variable1, shortDescription(this from database which is available in existingSomeNumberAndShortDescriptionList),

and variable1, Y or N if someNumber is available in List it than `Y` else `N`

Comment: How to use key "1" in someMap ? Is it same as getSomeNumber() in VO ?

Comment: Thanks Java Learner, yes

Comment: Is there any mapping between key in someMap with the someNumber in SomeVO object? On what basis you need to compare the map? Comparison to be done with key on someMap with someNumber in SomeVO object?

Comment: what do you finally want is not very clear; can you re-phrase the question pls.

Comment: @Jayaprasad you are right, both if both the value is right than the map will be like someNumber and shortDescription and second map will be someNumber and Y :)

Comment: You have to basically verify that someNumber on SomeVO object is present in the someMap? Firstmap --> Key= variableX value= shortdesc, SecondMap --> key=someNumber value=Y or N.. am i correct??!!

Comment: @Jayaprasad yes jayaprasad. :) thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will be like this :

```
public class Test {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {


    // Loaded Hashmap-------------------------------------------------------------------

    HashMap<Long, String> someMap= new HashMap<Long, String>();
    someMap.put(1L, "variable1");
    someMap.put(2L, "variable2");
    someMap.put(3L, "variable3");
    someMap.put(4L, "variable4");
    someMap.put(5L, "variable5");


    // List getting from db-------------------------------------------------------------------

    List<SomeVO> existingSomeNumberAndShortDescriptionList  = new ArrayList<SomeVO>();

    SomeVO someVO1=new SomeVO();
    someVO1.setSomeNumber(1L);
    someVO1.setShortDesc("Description 1");

    SomeVO someVO2=new SomeVO();
    someVO2.setSomeNumber(2L);
    someVO2.setShortDesc("Description 2");

    existingSomeNumberAndShortDescriptionList.add(someVO1);
    existingSomeNumberAndShortDescriptionList.add(someVO2);

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    HashMap<String, String> hashmap1 =new HashMap<String, String>();
    HashMap<Long, String> hashmap2 =new HashMap<Long, String>();

    //Iterate through list of bean
    for (Iterator<SomeVO> iterator = existingSomeNumberAndShortDescriptionList .iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        SomeVO someVO = (SomeVO) iterator.next();

        // Compare key with main hashmap and Put in hashmap 1
        hashmap1.put(someMap.get(someVO.getSomeNumber()),someVO.getShortDesc());

        // Compare key with main hashmap and check if number exists and Put in hashmap 2
        if(someMap.containsKey(someVO.getSomeNumber()))
            hashmap2.put(someVO.getSomeNumber(),"Y");
        else
            hashmap2.put(someVO.getSomeNumber(),"N");
    }


    // print hashmaps
    System.out.println(hashmap1);
    System.out.println(hashmap2);

}
```

And output will be..

```
{variable1=Description 1, variable2=Description 2}
{1=Y, 2=Y}
```

Comment: Some explanation would be nice.